# How to limit access for a user within Windows

Tags: windows, security, user-permissions, build-server

I want to allow people to build their Electron apps on a Windows environment. For me to do this, I accept jobs in via SQS and have a listener that runs the build process within a "workspace" folder.

I do not want to leave myself open to a malicious build script that will attempt to break out of the project's workspace and access anything it's no meant to.

How would I achieve this on the Windows operating system? (Using Windows Server 2016) I'm aware of NTFS folder permissions, but I don't know how I would implement the system using them.